# Plagued by error CS0117: 'Resource *' does not contain a definition for *

Tags: xamarin.android

Loading older Android Xamarin projects work as expected, but when I make a new project with AppCompatActivity (which is the only difference I can see) I get all resources showing this error. Not one is passing. Yet all are in the resource Designer

I have stripped out any Xml this I think might be causing the issue. Removed any fill_parents and replaced them with match-parent.

Deleted projects from the Obj / Debug folder

My resource designer has a ton of entries that I didn't make, which I presume are new action settings etc. But the expected settings are there.

I DL'ed the new VS Preview and loaded that up in the hope that it was something in the existing Enterprise VS, and disabled any Xamarin extensions I used.

Comment: I solved it by starting a new app and moving the code across to that one. Also moved my setcontentview to the cop of the Create method.  It seems to work. Yet the same edits on the original didn't work.

Comment: It ONLY works on VS Preview 15.8.0, it fails with xaml errors about Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar on 15.7.1

Comment: Hello, have you solved your problem?

Comment: Yes thank you Moving to Preview and starting from scratch, copying over the code to a new project.

Comment: Good luck! You can provide an answer, so it will help other people.